# split String by two separator (, and "") in Scala

Tags: regex, scala, apache-spark

I have a record like below.

> 1,2018,Abc,2018-04-19,Abc,Abc,Abc,b,n,0,Abc,33,0,Abc,**"Sql, Xyz"**,Abc,Abc,

I wanted to split the string by "," comma separator but I want **Sql,Xyz** as a single string not two different string like **"Sql** adn **Xyz"**.
So can someone please help me here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try using CSV-parsing libraries that handle this and more, e.g. https://github.com/tototoshi/scala-csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you.

```scala
def mySplit(str: String): List[String] = {
  var elems = List[String]()

  // break down by quotes first
  val quotes = str.split("\"")
  for(i <- 0 to quotes.length - 1) {

    if(i % 2 == 0) {
      // break down by commas second
      val subelems = quotes(i).split(",")
      for(j <- 0 to subelems.length - 1) {
        if(!subelems(j).isEmpty)
          elems = elems :+ subelems(j)
          // ignore empty elements
      }

    } else {
      // save "whole strings" and
      // don't break into commas
      elems = elems :+ quotes(i)
    }
  }

  return elems
}
```

Use it like so:

```
// quick test
val str = "1,2018,Abc,2018-04-19,Abc,Abc,Abc,b,n,0,Abc,33,0,Abc,\"Sql, Xyz\",Abc,Abc"
val list = mySplit(str)
```

Here is the [scalafiddle.io](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/Iu8AcCD/0)

Answer (score 0):

I have done, by using regex like below

```
val str= "1,2018,Abc,2018-04-19,Abc,Abc,Abc,b,n,0,Abc,33,0,Abc,\"Sql, Xyz\",Abc,Abc"
val list=str.split(",(?=(?:[^\\\"]*\\\"[^\\\"]*\\\")*[^\\\"]*$)")

list.foreach( x => println(x))
```